# Execute sbt task with modified dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to create a custom `runLocal` task that executes the sbt `run` task with modified `unmanagedClasspath`.
I want the `unmanagedClasspath` modification to only be visible/last while running `runLocal`, not `run`.
What I've tried in `build.sbt`:

```scala
Runtime / unmanagedClasspath ++= Seq(new java.io.File("src/main/my_resources")).classpath
val runLocal = taskKey[Unit]("Run app with my config")
runLocal := {
  (Runtime / run).toTask("").value
}
```

The above works but the problem is that the modification of `unmanagedClasspath` is "global" and affects every task that uses this value.
How can I run `runLocal` with modified `unmanagedClasspath` that is not visible outside that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using a `Command`.
Commands have access to the state and are able to modify it.

```
val runLocal = Command.command("runLocal") { state =>
  val extracted = Project.extract(state)
  val localConfigClasspath = Seq(new java.io.File("src/main/my_resources")).classpath
  val newState = extracted.appendWithoutSession(Seq(Runtime / unmanagedClasspath ++= localConfigClasspath), state)
  Project.extract(newState).runInputTask(Runtime / run, "", newState)._1
}
```

This way the config is only changed while running `sbt runLocal` without affecting `sbt run`.